# applescript - How to convert youtube link text to embed html text?

Tags: applescript, copy-paste, youtube

i want to convert 'youtube link text (from clipboard)'
to
'youtube title and embed html text'
and
copy to clipboard

With Applescript

for example,

1. I copy

   ```
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBGaO89cBMI
   ```

into clipboard

2. run a applescript
3. then the text (Title and EmbedHTML)

   ```
   Radiohead - Lift<p><iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QBGaO89cBMI?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   ```

copied into clipboard

Comment: Was my answer of any help to you?

Answer (score 1):

This *first* **AppleScript** *script* performs based on the steps outlined in your question.

```
tell current application
    set theURL to the clipboard
    if theURL contains "youtube" then
        try
            set theVideoID to do shell script "sed -e 's#.*=##'<<<" & the quoted form of theURL
            set theVideoTitle to do shell script "curl -s " & theURL & " | grep 'eow-title' | sed -e 's#.*title=\"##' -e 's#\">.*##'"
            set theEmbedLinkSeg1 to "<p><iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            set theEmbedLinkSeg2 to "el=0&amp;showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
            set the clipboard to theVideoTitle & theEmbedLinkSeg1 & theVideoID & theEmbedLinkSeg2
        on error
            display dialog "An error occured during processing. Check the URL and or Script Code." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with title "Processing Error"
            return
        end try
    else
        display dialog "The URL on the Clipboard did not contain a YouTube URL in the expected format." buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Processing Error"
        return
    end if
end tell
```

Assuming no *error* occurred, the **Clipboard** now contains the emebbed link information.

---

If by chance you're doing this in **Safari**, and are at the **YouTube** *page* and want to process, without having to first copy the *target* **URL** to the **Clipboard** and be faster then using `curl`, as in the *first script* to get the *title* (`theVideoTitle`), then the following **AppleScript** *script* is another way to go.

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1
        set theURL to (get URL)
        set theVideoTitle to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('eow-title').innerText;"
    end tell
end tell

tell current application
    if theURL contains "youtube" then
        try
            set embedLinkSeg1 to "<p><iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            set embedLinkSeg2 to "el=0&amp;showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
            set theVideoID to my getVideoID(theURL)
            set the clipboard to theVideoTitle & embedLinkSeg1 & theVideoID & embedLinkSeg2
        on error
            display dialog "Please verify Safari's current tab is at YouTube with the expected URL format." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with title "Processing Error"
            return
        end try
    else
        display dialog "Safari's current tab is not at YouTube." & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
            "Please select the correct tab and try again." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Processing Error"
        return
    end if
end tell

on getVideoID(theTextString)
    set TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"="}
    set theTextString to text item 2 of theTextString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    return theTextString
end getVideoID
```

Assuming no *error* occurred, the **Clipboard** now contains the embed link information.

---

If you're using **Google Chrome**, then change the following lines in the *second* **AppleScript** *script* as follows:

Change:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1
    set theVideoTitle to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('eow-title').innerText;"
```

To:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of window 1
    set theVideoTitle to execute javascript "document.getElementById('eow-title').innerText;"
```

Also change `Safari's` in the `display dialog` *commands* to: `Google Chrome's`

---

Note: In the first **AppleScript** *script*, getting the *value* of the *variable* `theVideoID` from the *value* of the *variable* `theURL` on the **Clipboard** is done using a `do shell script` *command* and `sed`, however it can be done using the `getVideoID` *handler* used in the *second* **AppleScript** *script*, as in the following:

```
tell current application
    set theURL to the clipboard
    if theURL contains "youtube" then
        try
            set theVideoID to my getVideoID(theURL)
            set theVideoTitle to do shell script "curl -s " & theURL & " | grep 'eow-title' | sed -e 's#.*title=\"##' -e 's#\">.*##'"
            set theEmbedLinkSeg1 to "<p><iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            set theEmbedLinkSeg2 to "el=0&amp;showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
            set the clipboard to theVideoTitle & theEmbedLinkSeg1 & theVideoID & theEmbedLinkSeg2
        on error
            display dialog "An error occured during processing. Check the URL and or Script Code." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with title "Processing Error"
            return
        end try
    else
        display dialog "The URL on the Clipboard did not contain a YouTube URL in the expected format." buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Processing Error"
        return
    end if
end tell

on getVideoID(theTextString)
    set TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"="}
    set theTextString to text item 2 of theTextString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    return theTextString
end getVideoID
```

Assuming no *error* occurred, the **Clipboard** now contains the emebbed link information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It doesn't include the starting bit with the title (not sure how to grab that best), but besides that, should work great.

```
set video_id to trimText(the clipboard, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "beginning")
set the clipboard to ("<p><iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" & (video_id) & "?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>")
display dialog (the clipboard)

on trimText(theText, theCharactersToTrim, theTrimDirection)
    set theTrimLength to length of theCharactersToTrim
    if theTrimDirection is in {"beginning", "both"} then
        repeat while theText begins with theCharactersToTrim
            try
                set theText to characters (theTrimLength + 1) thru -1 of theText as string
            on error
                -- text contains nothing but trim characters
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    if theTrimDirection is in {"end", "both"} then
        repeat while theText ends with theCharactersToTrim
            try
                set theText to characters 1 thru -(theTrimLength + 1) of theText as string
            on error
                -- text contains nothing but trim characters
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    return theText
end trimText
```

If you don't want it popping up with a dialog box every time, just delete the third line.